# Structure of Singly Linked List has me confused

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++14, singly-linked-list

So the reason I'm creating this is because for my C++ class we are given code that we have to build on. (and around) And the way my professor has written these Nodes out has me confused as to how they're linked.

I've been looking at many different resources including youtube videos for linked lists and those make sense with how you have a temp and head node.

```
struct NodeType 
       {
       int info;
       NodeType * link;
       };


int main()
{

    NodeType *ptr, *list;

    ptr = new NodeType;
    ptr->info = 16;
    ptr->link = nullptr;
    list = ptr;

    ptr = new NodeType;
    ptr->info = 28;
    ptr->link = nullptr;
    list->link = ptr;

    ptr = new NodeType;
    ptr->info = 52;
    ptr->link = list;
    list = ptr;
 }
```

The way I'm visualizing it is this:

1. We create a node *ptr*
2. We set the integer field info = 16
3. We set the link field of ptr = NULL
4. We set the address of list = ptr so that list references ptr
5. We create a new node and set the data field to 28
6. We set the link field = NULL
7. We point the link field of node list to ptr
8. We create a new node with info = 52
9. We point the link field equal to the memory address of list
10. We point the node list (or maybe it's mem address?) to the current ptr node

Here's an Image of what I'm thinking it looks like. ->

[image: Diagram]

My question is, what are these nodes supposed to look like when all pointing to each other and from my Diagram, what's wrong.

Comment: With a linked list, when creating a new node you usually make it's link pointer point to the current start of the list, and then change the list pointer to point to the new node. I'm not sure if you've actually asked a specific question, by the way...

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to look at this without redefining any variables.

```
struct NodeType 
{
    int info;
    NodeType * link; 
    // Following node
};

int main()
{
    NodeType * middle = new NodeType;
    middle->info = 16;
    // We don't have the next node yet
    // middle->link exists as a name, 
    // and we really should give it a value soon

    NodeType * last = new NodeType;
    last->info = 28;
    last->link = nullptr;
    // There is no next node, this is the final node
    middle->link = second;
    // Good, we have a value for middle->link now

    NodeType * first = new NodeType;
    first->info = 52;
    first->link = middle;
    // The next node is already present

    NodeType * list = first; 
    // A pointer is a value we can copy  

    // Usage and cleanup ommitted
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you finally got is a list like:

`52->16->28`

First, you create a node with a 16 inside, and you call it `list`

Second, you create another node with a 28, and point the `list->link` to it, so you have a list, which initial node is the one with 16 and this one points to the 28 one

Finally, you create a node with 52, and sets its `link` to the list, so, the next node of this node will be the whole list. Then, you decide to call this new node `list`.

**Update**

I add a diagram
[image: Step by step diagram]

Comment: Looks correct to me. There might be an implicit assumption here, that benefits from being made explicit. `NodeType * link` can point to zero or one `NodeType` objects, but not two. However, you can have two _different_ pointers to one object. It's a N:1 relation. (As opposed to `std::unique_ptr<NodeType>`)